# How can i format array object key using JavaScript

Tags: php

I have the array in a variable

```
var flaredata = [
   {
      "name":"flare.international.Arctic Council",
      "size":3812,
      "imports":
         "flare.interest.Climate & Environment, flare.interest.Economy,flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence,flare.interest.Health & Social,flare.interest.Inuit Interests"
      
   }
];
```

But I want an array in this format in which object key is also in double-quotes **using JavaScript how can I format array like this** also add [] after import ends and before import start

```
var flaredata = [
   {
      "name":"flare.international.Arctic Council",
      "size":3812,
      "imports":[
         "flare.interest.Climate & Environment",
         "flare.interest.Economy",
         "flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence",
         "flare.interest.Health & Social",
         "flare.interest.Inuit Interests"
      ]
   }
];
```

Comment: use JSON.stringify() -> flaredata.map(data => JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the imports property from all the [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), then return a new object [`spreading`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) out the rest parameters, and updating `imports` by splitting it into a new array.

Note: because your input data isn't standard (either `,` or `,` ) we can use a regex in the `split` to check for both instances.

```js
const flaredata = [{"name":"flare.international.Arctic Council","size":3812,"imports": "flare.interest.Climate & Environment,flare.interest.Economy,flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence,flare.interest.Health & Social,flare.interest.Inuit Interests"}];

const result = flaredata.map(({ imports, ...rest }) => {
  return {
    ...rest,
    imports: [imports.split(/, ?/)]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can i add [] add [] after import ends and before import start

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you update your question with your this output. @AnvitaRastogi

Comment: I already updated as you can see in the "import": [] are missing
but in the required output [] are there

Comment: yes but  brackets need to be add to work import as an array this is my real question

Comment: I've updated my answer @AnvitaRastogi

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `imports` childens by `.split(",").map(x => x.trim());`. And use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to process `flaredata`.

**Updated:** Fixed split `flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence` by comma.

```js
var flaredata = [{
  "name": "flare.international.Arctic Council",
  "size": 3812,
  "imports": [
    "flare.interest.Climate & Environment, flare.interest.Economy,flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence,flare.interest.Health & Social,flare.interest.Inuit Interests"
  ]
}];

var result = flaredata.map(item => {
   item.imports = item.imports[0]
   .split("flare.interest.")
   .filter(x => x.length > 0)
   .map(x => (('flare.interest.' + x).trim().replace(/,\s*$/, "")));
   
   return item;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your code also splits `Security, Safety & Defence`

Comment: @kol Well, I see. Let me fix it. Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Please use split function and concat function.

```js
const flaredata = [
   {
      "name":"flare.international.Arctic Council",
      "size":3812,
      "imports":[
         "flare.interest.Climate & Environment, flare.interest.Economy,flare.interest.Security, Safety & Defence,flare.interest.Health & Social,flare.interest.Inuit Interests"
      ]
   }
];

const result = flaredata.map(val => ({ ...val, "imports": [[]].concat(val["imports"][0].split(',')).concat([[]])}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: add [] after import ends and before import start

Comment: Same problem as [Tartarus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348884/215552) [originally had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348743/how-can-i-format-array-object-key-using-javascript#comment122572426_69348884).